# Transfer contact groups from Nagios to Check_MK

Tags: monitoring, nagios, check-mk

I have Nagios installed with proper configuration files. I have created some contact groups and assign them to hosts.

For web UI I'm using Check_MK, which is a great Nagios plugin. And here's the question:

Check_MK supports showing hosts/services based on contactgroup membership. But I can't transfer my Nagios contactgroups into Check_MK. (Result should be that if person XYZ is logged in, he see only hosts and services assigned to him.)

My users are in LDAP (I'm using Check_MK login form, not apache authorization).

I can't find any information about this in documentation so if someone have experiences, pls tell me how it works :) I'll appreciate that :)